# How to Slect Multiple Elements(Sprites) In Project window in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to select multiples sprites (16 in my case) in the project window to drag and drop them in the Hierarchy window.

Here's what I try to do :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvzCt.png)

Like I said it's just selecting all the sprites at once and drag them into The window above

I tied to press left mouse button and go down to select them all but it doesn't work.

I also tried to press ctrl + leftclick to select or shift + leftclick it do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to shift-click on the first sprite and then click on all the other sprites. After that you can drag them into an animation.